# Create a two-way table from dictionary of combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm writing a simple code to have a two-way table of distances between various cities.

Basically, I have a list of cities (say just 3: Paris, Berlin, London), and I created a combination between them with itertools (so I have Paris-Berlin, Paris-London, Berlin-London). I parsed the distances from a website and saved them in a dictionary (so I have: `{Paris: {Berlin : 878.36, London : 343.67}, Berlin : {London : 932.14}}`).

Now I want to create a two way table, so that I can look up for a pair of cities in Excel (I need it in Excel unfortunately, otherwise with Python all of this would be unnecessary!), and have the distance back. The table has to be complete (ie not triangular, so that I can look for London-Paris, or Paris-London, and the value must be there on both row/column pair). Is something like this possible easily? I was thinking probably I need to fill in my dictionary (ie create something like `{ Paris : {Berlin : 878.36, London 343.67}, Berlin : {Paris : 878.36, London : 932.14}, London : {Paris : 343.67, Berlin : 932.14}`), and then feed it to Pandas, but not sure it's the fastest way.  Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does something like what you need:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Paris': {'Berlin': 878.36, 'London': 343.67}, 'Berlin': {'London': 932.14}}

# Create data frame from dict
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Rename index
df.index.name = 'From'
# Make index into a column
df = df.reset_index()
# Turn destination columns into rows
df = df.melt(id_vars='From', var_name='To', value_name='Distance')
# Drop missing values (distance to oneself)
df = df.dropna()
# Concatenate with itself but swapping the order of cities
df = pd.concat([df, df.rename(columns={'From' : 'To', 'To': 'From'})], sort=False)
# Reset index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     From      To  Distance
0  Berlin   Paris    878.36
1  London   Paris    343.67
2  London  Berlin    932.14
3   Paris  Berlin    878.36
4   Paris  London    343.67
5  Berlin  London    932.14
```

Comment: Awesome! Though I changed df = pd.concat([df, df.reindex(columns=['To', 'From', 'Distance'])], sort=False) to df = pd.concat([df, df.rename(columns={'From' : 'To', 'To': 'From'})]), as yours was basically recreating the same df without changing the order (as you can see from your table, you have Berlin-Paris 2 times, but no Paris-Berlin). Works like a charm though!